# Can't edit entry created by another user after update to EE 2.7.3

Tags: members, member-management, update

After updating to ExpressionEngine 2.7.3 from ExpressionEngine 2.5.5 I get a "You are not authorized to perform this action" form error when attempting to update an entry created by another author. After turning on every option available in the member group that is attempting to make the edit I then get another error when attempting to edit the same entry "The selected author is invalid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know solution in the EllisLab bug reports:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20084

> Please make sure these seemingly unrelated settings are set:
>
> The original author’s group has to have “Include Members in PUBLISH page multi-author list?” set to “Yes”
>
> The person attempting to make the edit must have “Can change the author name when posting channel entries” set to “Yes”